# i cannot stop/pause a song in audioplayers

Tags: flutter, dart, audio-player

I am using the `audioplayers` plugin in my code.

I can play audio but I cannot stop/pause audio. Following is a function that I use to play/stop the audio.

```dart
  Future<void> onPlay({@required filepath, @required index}) async {
    AudioPlayer audioPlayer = AudioPlayer(mode: PlayerMode.MEDIA_PLAYER);
    if (!_isPlaying) {
      int result = await audioPlayer.play(filepath, isLocal: true);
      if (result == 1) {
        setState(() {
          _isPlaying = true;
          _selectedIndex = index;
        });
      }
    } else {
      int result = await audioPlayer.stop();
      if (result == 1) {
        setState(() {
          _isPlaying = false;
        });
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're instantiating a new `AudioPlayer audioPlayer` object each time you call `onPlay`, which leaves you unable to stop that same player later.

Store your `AudioPlayer audioPlayer` in the state somewhere.

```dart
AudioPlayer audioPlayer = AudioPlayer(mode: PlayerMode.MEDIA_PLAYER);

Future<void> onPlay({@required filepath, @required index}) async {
  if (!_isPlaying) {
    int result = await audioPlayer.play(filepath, isLocal: true);
    if (result == 1) {
      setState(() {
        _isPlaying = true;
        _selectedIndex = index;
      });
    }
  } else {
    int result = await audioPlayer.stop();
    if (result == 1) {
      setState(() {
        _isPlaying = false;
      });
    }
  }
}
```